# Azure CDN Verizon Standard can't see rules engine and need to forward http to https

Tags: rule-engine, azure-cdn, azure-static-website-hosting

I have a static web site hosted on blob storage in Azure.  I create an Azure CDN profile using Verizon standard account.  I need to forward http requests to https automatically.  I see a bunch of articles showing how ot do this with the rules engine but I cant seem to access it on my endpoint.